# Swype keyboard not swyping

Tags: keyboard, swype

Yesterday I installed Swype Keyboard to replace SlideIT. At first Swype was working but today it only lets me press the keys and not drag my finger. I think I briefly saw a message saying "dragging is not allowed in this mode" but it went away fast. I've tried disabling and enabling and selecting Swype again but not good. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you use Link2SD or Apps2SD and move either the Swype App or the Swype installer App to your SD card. To fix it, move the installer and Swype back to the phone and reboot.

I found some of this information on http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1042241 the rest I figured out by trying things.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a licensing issue.

You should uninstall Swype and then use the Swype installer to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say anything about what phone or Android version you currently have. But Android 4.2 includes now a Swype-like gestual typing keyboard.

There is a downloadable version for you to install, if your phone supports it.

[Try out the new Android 4.2 keyboard now!](http://www.intomobile.com/2012/10/30/try-out-new-android-42-keyboard-now/)